# Mongodb error - Out of file descriptors. Waiting one second before trying to accept more connections

Tags: mongodb, file-descriptors

Details

**Here is what I see in the logs file**

```
2014-09-08T10:22:43.143+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR: Out of file descriptors. Waiting one second before trying to accept more connections.
2014-09-08T10:22:43.360+0000 [conn9206] Assertion: 12520:new file allocation failure
```

**System Resource limit details** -

ulimit -a

```
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

**System Details**

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

**MongoDB Version**

2.6.1

Also,

**lsof -p mongopid**

2028 open file descriptors

Can anyone help ..? I am getting this repeatedly on my production server.. Looked on google.. Found this mongo issue closed -

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6734

Comment: Your ulimit settings are too low for mongod. Low ulimits can restrict the # of connections mongod can accept. I would start by updating nproc and no file in /etc/security/limits.conf for either all users or your mongod user. Details on how to change are available here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/

Comment: I would also take a look at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your open files are too little. You must add some lines on the following configuration files (and change `mongouser` for the username that runs MongoDB):

**/etc/security/limits.conf**

```
mongouser soft nofile 32768
mongouser hard nofile 65535
```

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
fs.file-max = 500000
```

**/etc/pam.d/login**

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

**/home/mongouser/.bashrc**

```
ulimit -n 63535
```

After rebooting the server the new limits will be in place.

Comment: nproc should be set as well, as per http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

Comment: I would also use the same soft nofile value as hard. mongod will use the soft limit as its upper bounds.

Comment: It would be nice if you briefed what each of the lines do and why the specific numbers?